# How to install debian on to a 16gb usb drive

Tags: debian

Debian is like 3 x 4GB ISO images but only have 1 16gb USB stick how I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need all three iso images - in fact, you typically only need the first one to install, and many users use the [mini ISO](https://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/) to install - this has a very small subset of packages, just enough to bootstrap an install. Just boot off the first disk, run the installer and you're good. You'll be able to pull whatever packages you need off of the internet.